# tableView cellForRowAt returning custom cell error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell-formatting

I have created a two classes of `NumberTableViewCell` and `YesNoTableViewCell` which both have a type of `UITableViewCell`. They have dynamic prototypes "attached" to them (Excuse me if I say things incorrectly, I am new to the lingo).

In `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` I connect to firebase and depending on a variable in the database, I either return one dequeued reusable cell, or the other. I have written out all of the code for this, however, the return gives me the error:

`Unexpected non-void return value in void function`.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    self.ref.child("campoutinfo").child("scoutQuestions").child("\(indexPath.row+1)").child("answer").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if "\(snapshot.value!)" == "1" {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yes-no_questionfield", for: indexPath) as! YesNoTableViewCell
            return cell
        } else if "\(snapshot.value!)" == "2" {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "number_questionfield", for: indexPath) as! NumberTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    })
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Keep in mind that I do have to also fit in somewhere the code: `cell.questionLabel.text = "\(snapshot.value!)"` Where would this belong?

Comment: **It is impossible to return something from within an asynchronous completion block**. You need to redesign the workflow.  Create a data source array, populate the data source array in `viewDidLoad` and reload the tableview.

Comment: Thanks! Once I made the change, everything worked out wonderfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In response to your original question, perhaps it could be because your if and else if is not exhaustive: i.e. if `snapshot.value!` is not equal to 1 or 2. Try replacing the else if with else, if these are the only two possible values of `snapshot.value!`